# Calculate the Time used by CountDownTimer Once it's started in java?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have countdowntimer Code which is working fine. But i want to calculate the time which is over once couterdowntimer is started running.

ex. If i have 2 hours running in countdowntimer. once it starts running i want to calculate time which is used like 2:00:00 hrs - 1:45:00 = 0:15:00

And show that time over in TimeOver TextView.

It should be dynamically changed along with countdowntimer running.

UI Screenshot:

[image]
[image]

This is my Code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEditTextInput;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown,mTextTimeOver;
    private Button mButtonSet;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;

    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

    private boolean mTimerRunning;

    private long mStartTimeInMillis;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
    private long mEndTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditTextInput = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_input);
        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
        mTextTimeOver = findViewById(R.id.text_view_timeOver)

        mButtonSet = findViewById(R.id.button_set);
        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);

        mButtonSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String input = mEditTextInput.getText().toString();
                if (input.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Field can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                long millisInput = Long.parseLong(input) * 60000;
                if (millisInput == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a positive number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                setTime(millisInput);
                mEditTextInput.setText("");
            }
        });

        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });

        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTime(long milliseconds) {
        mStartTimeInMillis = milliseconds;
        resetTimer();
        closeKeyboard();
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;

        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateWatchInterface();
            }
        }.start();

        mTimerRunning = true;
        updateWatchInterface();
    }

    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        updateWatchInterface();
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mStartTimeInMillis;
        updateCountDownText();
        updateWatchInterface();
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int hours = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
        int minutes = (int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

        String timeLeftFormatted;
        if (hours > 0) {
            timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                    "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
        } else {
            timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                    "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        }

        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    private void updateWatchInterface() {
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mEditTextInput.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonSet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            mEditTextInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mButtonSet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");

            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < mStartTimeInMillis) {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeKeyboard() {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putLong("startTimeInMillis", mStartTimeInMillis);
        editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
        editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);

        editor.apply();

        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

        mStartTimeInMillis = prefs.getLong("startTimeInMillis", 600000);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", mStartTimeInMillis);
        mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);

        updateCountDownText();
        updateWatchInterface();

        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
            mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateCountDownText();
                updateWatchInterface();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your example for a mentioned scenario?

Comment: hey if suppose i have set 2 hours of counterDowntimer. Once the countdowntimer started working the time start reducing. so i want to find the used time by coutdowbtimer while it's getting reduce? Total Time - Reducing Time = ?